# How to create custom permission which doesn't allow user to create/rename/delete folder in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-library, sharepoint-addin

I have created folders and linkup with navigation but this navigation folders need to be restricted. I created permission level which doesn't allow user to create/delete/rename folder but user can add files to this folder but when I use apply this permission for folder its not allowing to save files in folder.

Can anyone help me in this?